# std::vector faster than std::unordered_set?

Tags: c++, performance, vector, stl, unordered-set

In my custom physics engine, the biggest bottleneck is a method that gets all bodies from the spatial partitioning (a 2D grid), and returns a collection containing only unique pointers to body.

```
template<typename T, typename V> bool contains(const T& mContainer, const V& mValue)
{
    return std::find(std::begin(mContainer), 
                     std::end(mContainer), mValue) != std::end(mContainer);
}

const vector<Body*>& GridInfo::getBodiesToCheck()
{
    bodiesToCheck.clear();
    for(auto& query : queries)
        for(auto& body : *query)
            if(!contains(bodiesToCheck, body)) bodiesToCheck.push_back(body);
    return bodiesToCheck;
}
```

Using a profiler shows that the bottleneck is in the "contains" method.

Obviously, an `std::unordered_set` would be the "ideal" solution here. However, it is a lot slower than the current solution. I've also tried `google::dense_hash_set`, which is faster than `std::unordered_set`, but still slower than the current solution.

```
const unordered_set<Body*>& GridInfo::getBodiesToCheck()
{
    bodiesToCheck.clear();
    for(auto& query : queries)
        for(auto& body : *query)
            /*if(!contains(bodiesToCheck, body))*/ bodiesToCheck.insert(body);
    return bodiesToCheck;
}
```

Why are the "correct" containers slower than a `std::vector`?

Is there any way I can speed up this method further?

Comment: The profiling results are just for `contains`? Remember searching set might be faster but inserting is a slower than vector.

Comment: I assume you didn't make such a mistake, but just to be really really sure, you didn't use `std::find` when you tried the `std::unordered_map`, did you?

Comment: @stardust_ Profiler shows "getBodiesToCheck()" method as the bottleneck. If I use the std::vector version, the bottleneck inside getBodiesToCheck() (bottleneck of the bottleneck :P) is the call to "contains"

Comment: @ChristianRau Nope, I removed the "contains" part.

Comment: @Vee yes that is what i am saying on the vector version the `find` might be the bottleneck. however in the set version `insertion` might be the bottleneck.

Comment: @stardust_ I understand. Do you think there is any way to speed up this method? Maybe using a custom stack allocator could improve the performance?

Comment: @Vee While my question (from the above comment) might have been a bit stupid at first, it seems many answerers are confused about some possible iteration over `std::unordered_set`. So it might help to clarifiy things if you just included your `std::unordered_set` solution alongside the existing `std::vector` code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two possibilities I can think of:

1. You have a small enough number of data elements that a linear search is faster than a hash-plus compare lookup.
2. You're using the same `contains` function to find an element in the `unordered_set`, instead of using the member function `find`.

Comment: As I only care about returning a collection of unique Body*, I didn't use "contains" or "find" on unordered_set. I just used insert expecting it to only be filled with unique elements.

Answer (score 1):

If the number of duplicate bodies isn't that high compared to the others, one option might be to just push all your bodies into the vector and remove the duplicates afterwards. But this will require a `std::sort` followed by an `erase(std::unique, end)`.

But it may be worth a try, considering that your vector seems to outplay a `std::unordered_set` anyway, which doesn't have the same memory locality and trivial access like a `std::vector`.

Comment: I tried it, but the performance is slower than what I currently have.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understand the problem correctly, but it seems that the lookup will be slower on `std::vector`/`std::find`, but iteration might be faster than with `std::unordered_set`. If that is the case, and you are not limited by memory constraints, you can mix both approaches:

Maintain both a `std::unordered_set` and a `std::vector` with the elements. Lookup inside the `std::unordered_set` to determine whether the element is already there, if it is not, add it to both containers. At the end iterate over the `std::vector`.

Note that you can provide hints to both containers regarding the 'expected' number of elements that they will contain, and that will reduce the number of memory allocations/rehashing.

Comment: I guess that `std::unique_set` should be a `std::unordered_set`? Other than that, I don't think there is any need for him to iterate over the `std::unordered_set`, at least not in the code snippet in question (and the one he profiled and wants to speed up). It's just `std::vector+std::find` vs `std::unordered_set::insert`, so in your case he would have the same overhead like his existing `std::unordered_set` solution *and* the overhead of a vector insert.

Comment: @ChristianRau: Yes, `unordered` (need to get caffeine infused immediately!)

Answer (score 0):

I run into a similar problem where a linear search is faster than a hash-plus compare lookup.(A support to Mark's first answer).

I try to use BFS to improve the CPU voxelization of a mesh. `std::unordered_set` is used to mark visited voxels. However, `unordered_set` is 100% slower than linearly iterating the space. With a profile comparison, I find that a linear search is faster if the ratio of active voxels over all visited voxels is higher than `3%`. Otherwise, BFS with `unordered_set` is better.

Answer (score -2):

Here is what you find in the std documentation:

"unordered_set containers are faster than set containers to access individual elements by their key, although they are generally less efficient for range iteration through a subset of their elements."

Well since the find method will eventually loop through a considerable number of elements thats probably the reason...

Maybe if you've used a costum hash function you should improve it to make it faster... Only thing I can think of...

Comment: But then again when using `unordered_map` there is absolutely no need for `std::find` anyway (and the OP confirmed to not have done such stupid mistake).

Comment: *"If you really need better performance, the only data container I can think of would be some kind of hash table"* - Uh...you mean...like a `std::unordered_set`?

Comment: Yeah, you're right... Unordered set is indeed an Hash table... My bad.