# When is it worth it to change from std::vector to std::unordered_set?

Tags: c++

I want to make a container with few elements and I will be just checking whether an element is part of that set or not.
I know a vector would not be the appropriate container if the set is big enough since each research would be worst-case O(n) and there are better options that use a hash function or binary trees.
However I was wondering what happens if my set has few elements (eg just 5) and I know it in advance, is it worth it to implement the container as a structure having a hash function?
Maybe if the set is not big enough the overhead introduced by having to apply the hash function is greater than having to iterate through 5 elements.

For example in C++ using std::unordered_set instead of std::vector.
As always, thank you

Comment: There are some bad assumptions in the question.

Comment: If your data set is small, ie less then the CPU cache, using a vector is hard to beat.  CPU's are built to do linear traversals.  Also, avoid the `std::unordered_nnn` containers.  They way they have to be implemented, they are basically a `std::vector<std::list<T>>` which is not a great data structure.

Comment: If you have data that reflects real usage, you should implement both and profile to determine which is most efficient for the program's access behavior.

Comment: For finding the point at which a tradeoff pays off, the only way to know is to try it both ways and measure.

Comment: This is the sort of thing you’d need to test and measure, as it depends on the particulars of what you are doing.  Often when the size of a data set is small, it doesn’t matter what you use as either container will perform adequately.

Comment: I am afraid it depends on more that the size, but also the type of elements. For complex types, each comparison could be expensive while the hashes could be cached (+ for set). On the other hand, for integer data, searching an integer in a short array is rather fast (+ for vector).

Comment: Use a `std::set` and profile your code. That's because it's the most natural container for what you want to do. If your profiler shows up that this introduces a bottleneck, then think about alternatives. Remember that `std::set` requires a good implementation of "less than". Even for a large object that's not too onerous since you can often yield the result quickly. For example we all know that antidisestablishmentarianism is less than floccinaucinihilipilification by looking at just the first character.

Comment: Don't get too hang up on Big-O complexity. For instance, n < 3*log2(n) for n < 10, even though O(log(n)) is "better" than O(n), and 3 is not an improbable factor for a more complex algorithm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many factors affecting the point where the `std::vector` falls behind other approaches. See *[std::vector faster than std::unordered_set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15880017/stdvector-faster-than-stdunordered-set)* and *[Performance of vector sort/unique/erase vs. copy to unordered_set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640107/performance-of-vector-sort-unique-erase-vs-copy-to-unordered-set)* for some of the reasons why this is the case. As a consequence, any calculation of this point would have to be rather involved and complicated. The most expedient way to find this point is performance testing.

Keep in mind that some of the factors are based on the hardware being used. So not only do you need performance testing on your development machine, but also performance testing on "typical" end-user machines. Your development machine can give you a gut check, though, (as can an online tool like [Quick Bench](https://quick-bench.com/)) letting you know that you are not even in the ballpark yet. (The intuition of individual programmers is notoriously unreliable. Some people see 100 as a big number and worry about performance; others don't worry until numbers hit the billions. Either of these people would be blown away by the others' view.)

Given the difficulty in determining the point where `std::vector` falls behind, I think this is a good place to give a reminder that [premature optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/premature-optimization/info) is usually a waste of time. Investigating this performance out of curiosity is fine, but until this is identified as a performance bottleneck,  don't hold up work on more important aspects of your project for this. Choose the approach that fits your code best.

*That being said, I personally would assume the break point is well, well over 10 items. So for the 5-element collection of the question, I would be inclined to use a vector and not look back.*

Comment: It occurred to me that comments on performance questions often say "test it and see", but how would someone know to do this? I did not find a duplicate, so I thought it would be appropriate to have a question-answer combo with this info that future readers might be able to find before they ask a question along these lines.

Comment: I like it, +1.  You could also add that use can use a tool like [quickbech](https://quick-bench.com/) for a quick gut check